# How the views are updated when i add the records to the base table

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a view generating from two main tables. When i add records to the one of the main tables the view doesn't get updated automatically. Even I tried using exec `sp_refreshview`   to make the views to get updated, it didn't work.

How do I get this view to updated?

Is there any different way? I am using Microsoft SQL.

The View definition is as follows...

```
create view hipo_view
as
select 
    hipo_list.companyName,
    hipo_list.hipoName,
    hipo_list.uNo,
    hipo_list.uCompany,
    hipo_list.employeeNo,
    employee_info.imageURL
From hipo_list, employee_info
where hipo_list.hipoName = employee_info.employeeName 
AND hipo_list.employeeNo = employee_info.employeeNo
```

Comment: What do you mean "the view doesn't get updated automatically"?  Views (unless materialized) basically substitute the code into a query where they are used.  They should always be using the latest version of the table.  Are you sure you are committing all the transactions around the `insert` statements?

Comment: If you copy/paste the SQL into Management Studio and run it on its own, do you see what you expect?

Comment: And to add to what Gordon's said, in SQL Server, it's version of materialized views (indexed views) can't become out of date either - they're maintained as part of each transaction against the base table(s). There aren't any deferred maintenance processes.

Comment: Off-topic, old style SQL joins are not recommended.  That a look [at this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), which advocates using [joins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt8wzxy4.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) instead.

Comment: Are you viewing `view`'s contents in Management Studio? Like: right click->select top... ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff When update the main table with more records (just a insert statement), the view doesn't show the newly added records when i use the select statement on that view.

Comment: @NisalMalindaLivera . . . Perhaps they are filtered out by the joins.

Comment: @NisalMalindaLivera  how do you define if view is updated or not? Is there any triggers on this tables?

Comment: Can you provide the actual data and where you see the view is not returning the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing that *can* get updated when you update the table. A view does not exist (unless it is indexed); it is just a shorthand for the query that forms it.

If your result in the view is not as expected, you should look into the view's query. You will find the error there.